# How to tail MacOS syslog inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, macos-big-sur

I am running Big Sur and Docker Desktop 3.2.2 and want to tail /private/var/log/system.log from inside a running container, however, new log entries don't appear once tailing starts. In Resources > File Sharing I added /private/var/log just in case. I start the container with this command:

```
docker run -v /private/var/log/:/test/ -it busybox tail -f /test/system.log
```

and it tails the log, but new entries don't get printed for some reason (green line is where it stops tailing inside the container). [image]

However, if I copy syslog and mount any other directory then tailing works as expected:

```
docker run -v /Users/username/Desktop/:/test/ -it busybox tail -f /test/system.log
```

[image]

So what is so special about /private/var/log that stops me from tailing it successfully since it clearly can be done from other directories mounted as volumes?

Comment: Have you tried this ?  
`https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/troubleshoot/`